# How do I hide Twitter updates on my LinkedIn home page?

Tags: twitter, linkedin

Is there a way to remove Twitter updates from showing on my LinkedIn homepage? This is just flooding my LinkedIn stream with redundant data that I don't want to know.

Comment: did you find a way to do this yet? (without entirely blocking the users).

Comment: @pvgoddijn - Unfortunately, not yet.

Answer (score 1):

There might be a setting you can change on this page;

https://www.linkedin.com/secure/settings?viewNUSPrefs

That controls how many updates you would like to see on your homepage and which types you would like to see.

Probably the hide 'Application updates from your connections' setting under Applications.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't help. Application updates are hidden, and yet the twitter entries keep coming :(

Comment: Have you tried clicking `hide` on rolling over the specific status ?  
This will hide all updates from the user.  

If you accepted their connection or vice versa, it is assumed you generally want to hear "professionally" what they have to say. It would not make sense to add a professional connection to someone who connected their empty/inactive LinkedIn account to their Twitter account.